# Deploy rails app to non-root context - restful_auth not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ruby-on-rails-plugins, passenger

I'm running a rails app on http://www.naildrivin5.com/scalatour.  It works fine.  When I log in to the app using `restful_authentication`, I get taken to the http://www.naildrivin5.com instead of the app.  Weird.

This seems like I've misconfigured something.  Further, there's a few places where I'm hand-creating some urls, and I need access to the "application context root" (i.e. `scalatour` in my case) to form the URL properly.  I ended up throwing it in my configuration, but this just seems wrong.

Apache, with Passenger, running a Rails app:

Apache conf:

```
<VirtualHost 69.89.3.135:80> 
  DocumentRoot /somewhere/naildrivin5.com/html
  ServerName naildrivin5.com 
  RailsBaseURI /scalatour  
  PassengerPoolIdleTime 5 
  # other things not related
</VirtualHost>
```

`passenger.conf`:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/share/passenger/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so 
PassengerRoot /usr/share/passenger 
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby 
PassengerLogLevel 2
```

`/somewhere/naildrivin5.com/html/scalatour` is symlinked to my Rails app's `public` folder.

The app works fine, **except** for authentication, using `restful_authentication`.  After I log in, I'm taken to the web server root, not the application root.

How should/can I configure this, how can I access this at runtime, and how can I best configure my local dev environment to do this (or not care about it)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short Answer

- setting `relative_url_root` in `environments/production.rb`
- creating a route called "home" to my home page
- Modifying the scaffolded `restful_authentication` code to redirect to home instead of `/`

### Details

If you're having troubles because of the suburi configuration, you should configure the [relative_url_root](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/AbstractRequest.html#M000432) in your environments/production.rb file:

```
config.action_controller.relative_url_root = "/scalatour"
```

In my opinion, the problem your describing here is a controller/routes issue and a possible solution may be the next:

1) I would configure these routes:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  [...]
  map.home 'home', :controller => 'welcome', :action => 'show'

  map.login "login", :controller => "user_sessions", :action => "new"

  map.logout "logout", :controller => "user_sessions", :action => "destroy"

  map.root :login
end
```

2) Then the UserSessions controller would look like:

```
class UserSessionsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_no_user, :only => [:new, :create]
  before_filter :require_user, :only => :destroy

  def new
    @user_session = UserSession.new
  end

  def create
    @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
    if @user_session.save
      redirect_back_or_default home_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "Sorry, unrecognized username or password."
      render :action => :new
    end
  end

  def destroy
    current_user_session.destroy
    redirect_back_or_default login_url
    reset_session()
  end
  end
```

3) Just for completeness, the methods "require_user" and "require_no_user" could be placed at the ApplicationController and would be:

```
  def require_user
    unless current_user
      flash[:error] = t("You must be logged-in to access this page")
      redirect_to login_path
      return false
    end
  end

  def require_no_user
    if current_user
      redirect_to home_path
      return false
    end
  end
```

Best regards

Comment: This was it; I'm going to edit the post to highlight exactly what needed doing.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad that helps you. Thank you for summarizing it!!